# How can i filter results in the view using includes in the controller in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, filter, include, nested-includes

I have this in my controller:

```
class User::ResourcesController < User::UserController
  def index
     @resource_type = ResourceType.find_by_name(params[:resource_type].to_s.titleize)
     @products = @products.includes(:resources).where(:resources => { :resource_type_id => @resource_type.id })

     respond_to do |format|
       format.html # index.html.erb
       format.xml  { render :xml => @resources }
     end
  end
end
```

I am trying to get my resources to be filtered so in my view i can use the code below and have it only pull the resources that have the correct resource_type_id.

```
@products.each do |product|
  product.resources.count
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@products = Product.includes(:resources).where("resources.resource_type_id = ?", @resource_type.id)
```

Comment: oops I just realized that you have @products = @products.inc.... (and I repeated it). Where is the original @products variable coming from?  Try my edited answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
@products = Product.includes(:resources).where(resources: { 
  resource_type_id: @resource_type.id 
})
```

It's safest and easier to read.